Group By on certain condition but should display all rows in the original data
I have the below Data



NAME
AMT
EID
Tran




John
4000
1
T1


Mary
5000
2
T2


John
8000
1
T3


Willi
5000
3
T4


Mary
1000
2
T5



I wanted to group by Name, EID and sum the AMT column but still show all the row values as in the below output



NAME
AMT
EID
Tran
Total Amt




John
4000
1
T1
12000


Mary
5000
2
T2
6000


John
8000
1
T3
12000


Willi
5000
3
T4
5000


Mary
1000
2
T5
6000



I have tried this , but it doesn't work and I am using MySQL 5.7 and it doesn't support LEAD and LAG either.
select SUM(AMT) as TotalAmt, * from mytable
group by NAME,EID

How do I get the output below ?



NAME
AMT
EID
Tran
Total Amt




John
4000
1
T1
12000


Mary
5000
2
T2
6000


John
8000
1
T3
12000


Willi
5000
3
T4
5000


Mary
1000
2
T5
6000




Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question

The simple way is to upgrade your MySQL version and then use a window sum:
SELECT
  NAME,
  AMT,
  EID,
  TRan,
  SUM(AMT) OVER(PARTITION BY NAME) AS `Total Amt`
FROM yourtable;

If you can't upgrade, you can use a subquery to fetch the sum for the current Name:
SELECT
  y_main.NAME,
  y_main.AMT,
  y_main.EID,
  y_main.TRan,
  (SELECT SUM(y_sub.AMT) FROM yourtable y_sub 
    WHERE y_sub.NAME = y_main.NAME) AS `Total Amt`
FROM yourtable y_main;

Upgrading and using a window sum is far simpler and faster because it prevents the tabe will queried twice. That's the reason why window functions have been introduced.
On this sample fiddle with your data in MySQL 8.0, both queries produce the expected result. If you change the version to 5.7 in the fiddle and run it again, the window sum won't work anymore because it's not supported there.

As suggested by @jonas right approach is to upgrade mysql and using analytical window function.
Just wanted to make a general point that for such scenarios where you want to group data on certain column and still want to view all the columns, over clause with partition by is the best solution. Partition By acts as a group by while still retaining all the columns.

If you are using MySQL version 8, using window function is more convenient compared to the convention way. But please note that a window function can disrupt the original display order with the partition parameter in the window frame. 
For instance, supposing our table is built with no index at all. Without defining a PK or unique key, MySQL uses the insert sequence as the cluster index. And a query will have to use a full table scan (as there is no index to use), which is based on the sequence of the cluster index. And without an ORDER BY clause, the query tends to return a result set in the order of cluster index sequence. Note I used the  phrase tends to, as I heard people say it is not absolutely the case.
create table test (NAME varchar(10),    AMT int,    EID int,    Tran char(2));
insert test values
('John',    4000,   1   ,'T1'),
('Mary',    5000,   2   ,'T2'),
('John',    8000,   1   ,'T3'),
('Willi',   5000,   3   ,'T4'),
('Mary',    1000,   2   ,'T5');

select * from test;
-- result set
+-------+------+------+------+
| NAME  | AMT  | EID  | Tran |
+-------+------+------+------+
| John  | 4000 |    1 | T1   |
| Mary  | 5000 |    2 | T2   |
| John  | 8000 |    1 | T3   |
| Willi | 5000 |    3 | T4   |
| Mary  | 1000 |    2 | T5   |
+-------+------+------+------+

Now we use a window function to get the desired Total Amount for each row:
select *, sum(amt) over (partition by name) as 'Total Amt'from test;
-- result set
+-------+------+------+------+-----------+
| NAME  | AMT  | EID  | Tran | Total Amt |
+-------+------+------+------+-----------+
| John  | 4000 |    1 | T1   |     12000 |
| John  | 8000 |    1 | T3   |     12000 |
| Mary  | 5000 |    2 | T2   |      6000 |
| Mary  | 1000 |    2 | T5   |      6000 |
| Willi | 5000 |    3 | T4   |      5000 |
+-------+------+------+------+-----------+

As we can see, the original order is altered due to the partition argument NAME in the window frame. If we require the result shown in original order, we need to set a row number for the original table:
select *, row_number() over() as seq from test;
-- result set
+-------+------+------+------+-----+
| NAME  | AMT  | EID  | Tran | seq |
+-------+------+------+------+-----+
| John  | 4000 |    1 | T1   |   1 |
| Mary  | 5000 |    2 | T2   |   2 |
| John  | 8000 |    1 | T3   |   3 |
| Willi | 5000 |    3 | T4   |   4 |
| Mary  | 1000 |    2 | T5   |   5 |
+-------+------+------+------+-----+

Now we can query the sequenced table to get our desired output in the original order with an ORDER BY clause on the seq.
select NAME,AMT,EID,Tran,sum(amt) over (partition by name) as 'Total Amt'
from (select *, row_number() over() as seq
      from test) t
order by seq
;  
-- result set
+-------+------+------+------+-----------+
| NAME  | AMT  | EID  | Tran | Total Amt |
+-------+------+------+------+-----------+
| John  | 4000 |    1 | T1   |     12000 |
| Mary  | 5000 |    2 | T2   |      6000 |
| John  | 8000 |    1 | T3   |     12000 |
| Willi | 5000 |    3 | T4   |      5000 |
| Mary  | 1000 |    2 | T5   |      6000 |
+-------+------+------+------+-----------+

And if you are using a version which does not support window function, such as MySQL 5.7, there is a way to complement the original sequence too.
select test.*, @row_number:=@row_number+1 as seq
from test, (select @row_number:=0) s ;
-- result set
+-------+------+------+------+------+
| NAME  | AMT  | EID  | Tran | seq  |
+-------+------+------+------+------+
| John  | 4000 |    1 | T1   |    1 |
| Mary  | 5000 |    2 | T2   |    2 |
| John  | 8000 |    1 | T3   |    3 |
| Willi | 5000 |    3 | T4   |    4 |
| Mary  | 1000 |    2 | T5   |    5 |
+-------+------+------+------+------+

Now, we can get our final result by joining the sequenced table with an aggregate table. The original sequence is intact with an ORDER BY clause on the seq.
select NAME,AMT,EID,Tran,sm as 'Total Amt'
from (select NAME,sum(AMT) sm
     from test
     group by NAME) t1
     join 
     (select test.*, @row_number:=@row_number+1 as seq
     from test, (select @row_number:=0) s ) t2
     using (NAME)
order by seq
;
-- result set
+-------+------+------+------+-----------+
| NAME  | AMT  | EID  | Tran | Total Amt |
+-------+------+------+------+-----------+
| John  | 4000 |    1 | T1   |     12000 |
| Mary  | 5000 |    2 | T2   |      6000 |
| John  | 8000 |    1 | T3   |     12000 |
| Willi | 5000 |    3 | T4   |      5000 |
| Mary  | 1000 |    2 | T5   |      6000 |
+-------+------+------+------+-----------+

Note: We can also use a correlated subquery instead of joining the aggregate table. Here is the pros and cons for doing so:
Pros
It is more straightforward and thus usually easier to comprehend than table joining as in latter case we need to analyze each table's content as well as the join condition.
Cons
It requires an individual SUM calculation for each row, while the aggregate table joining method only needs to perform the SUM calculation  once(to get the aggregate table ).

As the question currently stands, there is no order. Having an order or sorting a result requires a column to sort by, for example an id or a date. When we have a column to sort and we want so sort, then we use an ORDER BY clause, no matter if with window function or not.
